# Minecraft Launcher: Launching Minecraft Java asks for Username Even When Already Has

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues, minecraft-launcher

I have already used Minecraft Java a few times to play Hypixel, but I stopped for a month or so to try out Bedrock. I know I still have an account (through checking my account in brower), but when I launch Java through my launcher, it asks for me to select a username (Yes, I've already tried my old username + using a new, different one) and it tells me there was an error. What is the solution to making Java load?